# How to use modelMapper to map to a nested DTO class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, modelmapper

Here is the class that I want to map to a DTO class using modelMapper. UserDTO class has property AddressDTO

```
public class UserDTO {
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean isActive;

    private AddressDTO address;
}
```

```
public class AddressDTO {

    public Long addressId;

    public String homeNumber;

    private City city;

    private District district;

    private Ward ward;
}
```

Please note that each user will have 0 or 1 address so that AdressDTO can be null. But when I use ModelMapper, it turns out to be null for all Users.

At first, I use constructor to map DTO manually.

```
private UserDTO mapToUserDTO(User user){
    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();

    userDTO.setId(user.getId());
    userDTO.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    userDTO.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    userDTO.setIsActive(user.getIsActive());

    Address address = addressRepository.findAddressByUser(user);
    if (address == null)
        userDTO.setAddress(null);
    else {
        AddressDTO addressDTO = mapper.mapToDTO(address, AddressDTO.class);
        userDTO.setAddress(addressDTO);
    }
    return userDTO;
}
```

The second time, I try fully with ModelMapper:

```
public DataResponse<List<UserDTO>> getAll() {
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
    List<UserDTO> userDTOs = userMapper.mapToDTOList(users, UserDTO.class);

    return new DataResponse<>(userDTOs);
}
```

So this time I try with ModelMapper and the AddressDTO appears to be null as I said before. Can anyone show me the way to fix it?

[Edited 1]
Here is the abstract class I create generic functions to mapToDTO

```
public class AbstractModelMapper <E,D>{
    @Autowired
    ModelMapper mapper;

    public D mapToDTO(E e, Class<D> d){ return e != null ? mapper.map(e,d) : null;}

    public E mapToEntity(D d, Class<E> e){ return d!= null ? mapper.map(d, e) : null;}

    public List<D> mapToDTOList(List<E> eList, Class<D> d){
        return eList != null ? eList.stream().map(e -> mapper.map(e,d)).collect(Collectors.toList()) : null;
    }
}
```

Then I create Component Class for each entity. Example:

```
@Component
public class UserMapper extends AbstractModelMapper<User, UserDTO> {
}
```

Lastly, I use it by using DI technique:

```
  @Autowired
    UserMapper userMapper;
```

I am wondering whether create another configuration class for a specific situation like this.

Comment: first: I hope you understand this code is pointless: if (address == null)
        userDTO.setAddress(null); secondly: what is the code of your mapper?

Comment: Are you using the mapper from `org.modelmapper`? Can you provide the bean definition of the `userMapper` injected within this classes.

Comment: I have just updated my question, and described my abstract class that include some generic methods that I used